# Insert data into mysql table from c++ program using OTL library

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, otl

I want to insert `int` and `string` value into mysql table from c++ program.

```
for (std::map < int, std::vector < std::string > >::iterator hit = three_highest.begin(); hit != three_highest.end(); ++hit) {
    //std::cout << hit->first << ":";

    for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator vit = (*hit).second.begin(); vit != (*hit).second.end(); vit++) {
        std::cout << hit->first << ":";
        std::cout << *vit << "\n";
```

I want to insert `hit->first` and `*vit`.

1. I saw example here : [OTL Example for mysql](http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_ex78.htm). Will it work for me?

   And how to set OTL environment in my system? Do I need to install it or what?
2. Here is very simple example in another way. But it directly `include <mysql.h>` Which I could not find in my system. What environment it using?

I am using Linux - Ubuntu environment.

Comment: i believe mysql isnt in /usr/include but /usr/include/mysql so you should be able to include it via `#include <mysql/mysql.h>` . For your other questions, use guidelines for mysql installation/setup on ubuntu. IT should already be there and maybe its deamon has to be run ( so its running ), then your program should run fine with mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got how to connect c++ with mysql:

first compiled the c++ connector library from source but after a while I thought maybe I did something wrong so I then just used apt to get it with:

```
sudo apt-get install  libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

So I have now had this problem for a week now and I became very frustrated with it as well. I just now was able to finally build a program that does nothing except login to mysql and I literally squealed with joy. Here is what I have and I hope it helps.

I first compiled the c++ connector library from source but after a while I thought maybe I did something wrong so I then just used apt to get it with:

sudo apt-get install  libmysqlcppconn-dev

And here is my simple tester source file "tester.cpp"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <driver.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <statement.h>

using namespace sql;
int main(void){
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;

  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","root","YOURPASSWORD");

  return 0;
}
```

And finally g++ compile command:

```
sudo g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/cppconn -o testapp tester.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```